# What happens to the screen when the paused activity gets destroyed?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

The activity is still visible when it's in the paused state, then what happens to the screen when it gets destroyed? Is the paused activity simply painted black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it:  created an activity, put another transparent activity above it so onPause gets called, and destroyed the paused activity.  The destroyed Activity disappears from the screen, and whatever was under it becomes visible, usually the home screen.